# minishift - Monitoring pods

Tags: openshift, monitoring, prometheus, minishift

As per the [documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html#overview_prometheus-cluster-monitoring), monitoring is shipped with OKD.

> OKD ships with a pre-configured and self-updating monitoring stack that is based on the Prometheus open source project and its wider eco-system. It provides monitoring of cluster components and ships with a set of alerts to immediately notify the cluster administrator about any occurring problems and a set of Grafana dashboards.

Further, as per the [documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html#accessing-prometheus-alertmanager-and-grafana_prometheus-cluster-monitoring), this command should show links for various monitoring tools. `oc -n openshift-monitoring get routes`

When I run the `oc` command with `system` user, I get a message as: `No resources found.`

The installation does not go through.

```
git clone https://github.com/openshift/cluster-monitoring-operator
cd cluster-monitoring-operator
oc apply -f manifests/
```

Error messages:

```
namespace "openshift-monitoring" created
serviceaccount "cluster-monitoring-operator" created
unable to decode "manifests/0000_50_cluster_monitoring_operator_02-role.yaml": no kind "ClusterRole" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to decode "manifests/0000_50_cluster_monitoring_operator_03-role-binding.yaml": no kind "ClusterRoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to decode "manifests/0000_50_cluster_monitoring_operator_04-deployment.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
unable to decode "manifests/0000_50_cluster_monitoring_operator_05-clusteroperator.yaml": no kind "ClusterOperator" is registered for version "config.openshift.io/v1"
unable to decode "manifests/0000_90_cluster_monitoring_operator_00-operatorgroup.yaml": no kind "OperatorGroup" is registered for version "operators.coreos.com/v1"
```

So, how do we enable monitoring with `minishift`?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to install prometheus in minishift:
https://github.com/minishift/minishift-addons/tree/master/add-ons/prometheus

Be sure that you login as admin. If you encounter problem to login as admin, you can follow these steps:

*minishift ssh*

*[docker@example ~]$ sudo su*

*[root@example ~]# export KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/minishift/base/openshift-apiserver/admin.kubeconfig PATH="$PATH:/var/lib/minishift/bin"*

*[root@example ~]# oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin admin*

*[root@example ~]# exit*

*[docker@example ~]$ exit*

*oc login -u admin -p admin*

*oc whoami*

You will see you login as admin.

When I enter the command to apply the prometheus, I encountered this problem:

*minishift addons apply prometheus --addon-env namespace=kube-system*

-- Applying addon 'prometheus':.Error applying the add-on: Error executing command 'oc new-app -f prometheus.yaml -p NAMESPACE=#{namespace} -n #{namespace}'.

**Solution:**

1. login Minishift as admin using "oc login -u admin -p admin".
2. go to the namespace "kube-system" by "oc project kube-system".
3. click on "Add to project" -> "import YAML/JSON".
4. clone the prometheus addon in your local machine from https://github.com/minishift/minishift-addons.git
5. import the ../minishift-addons/add-ons/prometheus/prometheus.yml into the "kube-system" namespace.

Afterwards, the prometheus will be deployed.
You can access the prometheus graph UI: https://prometheus-kube-system.$minishift-host-ip-address.nip.io.